# How to handle jwt authentication between backend server on diffrent url and frontend on diffrent url?

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, authorization, next.js13

I am making a web application using latest nextjs 13(typescript) with App router,
this application has 1 backend server which acts as a rest api server connected to mongodb,
and frontend communicates to the backend server for any request and resources.

So my backend server is returning me `accessToken` and `refreshToken` in response data, as to avoid any corss domain issues, this access token includes of `session`, `user`(info), `expiry`, session has a session id, and in db sessions are stored as `{userId, valid, userAgent, id, timestamps}` and thinking of storeing more info later in future, valid is a boolean object if true the session is valid and is token is valid, if not valid then tokens are of no use with this session id inside.

So i am not sure how i save the tokens, and handle the workflow of the authentication,
as of now i thought of approach is, use NextjsApi with route handlers `/api/login` i will send email and password as body data to it and then this api will request the backend to create session and if valid data, then tokens recieved to be saved in cookies so the cookies will be saved in browswer by same doamin as frontend, then fetching those cookies everytime user request any data, by fetching token and passing them in authorization header.
But I also saw in nextauth that it chhecks the jwt right there on client so authentication is more smooth, i also have public key to decode the jwt and a middlewar in nextjs that sees first if cookies are present or not, in present it redirects to /app/dashboard

```
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server"

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export async function middleware(
    request: NextRequest,
    res: NextResponse,
    req: any
) {
    const cookies = request.cookies
    const isAuth = !!cookies.has("accessToken")
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
    requestHeaders.set('x-hello-from-middleware1', 'hello')
    const isAuthPage =
        request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") ||
        request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/register")
    if (isAuthPage) {
        if (isAuth) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/app/dashboard", request.url))
        }
        return null
    }

    if (!isAuth) {
        let from = request.nextUrl.pathname
        if (request.nextUrl.search) {
            from += request.nextUrl.search
        }

        return NextResponse.redirect(
            new URL(`/login?from=${encodeURIComponent(from)}`, request.url)
        )
    }

    // return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
    matcher: ["/app/:path*", "/login", "/register"],
}
```

but the thing is i also need to check session ID then if its valid or not. Please some one guide me to perfect approach or way to do this or handle this things, what can be the perfect approach here.

Comment: i am literally doing the same thing. Did you find any alternate approach ? Also, how are you handling access token expiration. i assume you using fetch instead of axios in server components ?